# SQL Syntax error (access violation: 1064)

Tags: mysql, left-join

here is an sql query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `actors` `t` WHERE company_name LIKE "%test%" 
LEFT JOIN `actors_adresses` ON `actors`.id = `actors_adresses`.actor
AND `actors_adresses`.adress LIKE "%test2%"
```

Please help me to find the mistake =(

Comment: "adress" is spelled "address", just for future reference

Comment: either you give alias name and use it else where or do not give at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try as per below-

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `actors` `t` 
LEFT JOIN `actors_adresses` a ON t.id = a.actor
WHERE t.company_name LIKE "%test%" 
AND a.adress LIKE "%test2%"
```

Comment: as you are using left join here so there can be different results if you use conditions in different way..so share what output you really required or simply you can use normal join instead of left join if you want to count just matching rows.

Answer (score 1):

Your Syntax is incorrect. Where is never between from and joins

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

Answer (score 1):

`WHERE` should come after `JOIN` per syntax. Your query should be

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM `actors` 
LEFT JOIN `actors_adresses` ON `actors`.id = `actors_adresses`.actor
// You can leave this condition here as JOIN condition
AND `actors_adresses`.adress LIKE '%test2%' 
WHERE `actors`.company_name LIKE '%test%'
```